# What FontFamily Fonts can I use in a ListBox?

Tags: .net, wpf, fonts, listbox

I'm trying to change the `FontFamily` of a `ListBox` to a fixed-width font, but I don't know what's available.  Here's what I have:

```
<ListBox Margin="12,55,12,12" Name="listBox1" FontFamily="Arial" />
```

When I try something like `FontFamily="Courier"`, it won't show up as Courier, which leads me to believe that font may not be available.  I've tried searching for the last 10 minutes, but I can't find a list of fonts that I can use by default in WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Courier New`.

Courier is a raster font, and raster fonts are not supported by WPF.

Courier New is a TrueType font, so it should work fine.

The easiest way to check for a specific font is to look in the Font dropdown in Word.
Raster fonts such as Courier will have a pixelated printer icon; TrueType fonts will have a TT or an *O*.

**EDIT**:

In answer to your comment, WPF can use any font installed on the *end-user*'s system.
[Here](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/windows-fonts-by-version.html) is a list of fonts included with each version of Windows.  These fonts will always be available.  If you want to use a different font, you'll have to distribute it with your app.  (And check the font's license terms)

Comment: I thought I had tried that, but I guess not, because it worked.  It'd still be cool to find a list of `FontFamily` fonts for reference, though.

Comment: A list of which `FontFamily` fonts?

Comment: ones that I can use in the `ListBox` control.  I don't know where WPF is looking to find fonts that it can use in the `ListBox` control.  Is it in the host operating system? The BCL? For example, `Courier New` works but `Courier` does not. What determines that and how do I know which fonts will work?

Comment: I guess I had to pick a non-true-type font to make this complicated :-). Thanks for your help.

Comment: sure, how much later? (I didn't think accepted answers affected the rep limit).

Comment: You deleted the comment where you asked me to wait to accept your answer so you could go over the rep limit.  That kind of makes my above reply sound a little silly :-).

Comment: You can delete your reply as well.